# unable to set session for multidimensional array in php opencart

Tags: php, opencart, php-5.3

I have the following opencart function to add product in session

Consider this as my `$bean_sku` and `$product_id`

```
$bean_id = 'werwer-23423s-sd-01';
$product_id = 120;

public function add($product_id, $bean_sku, $qty = 1, $option = array()) {

    if (!$option) {
          $key = (int)$product_id;
    } else {
          $key = (int)$product_id . ':' . base64_encode(serialize($option));
    }

    if ((int)$qty && ((int)$qty > 0)) {
        if (!isset($this->session->data['cart'][[$bean_sku][$key]])) { echo 'not set';
              $this->session->data['cart'][[$bean_sku][$key]] = (int)$qty;
        } else { echo 'session set';
              $this->session->data['cart'][[$bean_sku][$key]] += (int)$qty;
            }
    }
    echo $this->session->cart;
    exit;
    $this->data = array();
}
```

In the above function I have added `$bean_sku` But I am unable to set the session. Each time when I run getting `not set`.

Comment: I think the problem is here: `echo $this->session->cart;` This will echo nothing. The `$this->session` is not an object, it is an array, so You have to do `print_r($this->session['cart']);` - then You'll see that even Your own code is working. But I still recommend using the code that Nouphal is suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
$this->session->data['cart'][$bean_sku.$key] = (int)$qty;
```

Comment: Tried then too unable to set

Comment: Are you able to get session data in this page?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$this->session->data['cart'][$bean_sku][$key]
```

instead of

```
$this->session->data['cart'][[$bean_sku][$key]]
```

Comment: still I cannot set it

Comment: If product id and bean_sku not exists have to add otherwise need to update the cart.

Comment: is this the  function in /system/library/cart.php

Comment: Yae its in /system/library/cart.php only

Comment: you can pass you $bean_sku through options, If u update the function you have to update all calling occurence of cart->add method.

Comment: But I am getting the bean_id inside my function. But I am unable to set it.

Comment: try printing $this->session->cart at the end of the function

Comment: check my edit tried printing at the end of the function returns empty

Comment: try printing $this->session->data['cart']

Comment: If I use `$this->session->data['test'][$bean_sku][$key] = 20;` its not working but If i use `$this->session->data['test'][$bean_sku] = 20;` it is working. Why this happens. Whether I can use only 2D array?